# Increase Ubuntu partition and Re-Install

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning

I have a Dual Boot Windows 10 / Ubuntu 16.04 setup.

So I want to do two things:
- have a clean fresh install of Ubuntu
- have it on a larger partition than it is right now

What I did so far:
I freed space from my Windows partition which gave me 150GB additional free space. Now, do I have to add this free space to my current Ubuntu partition and then re-install or can I just insert a Ubuntu 16.04 bootable USB stick and in the partition menu wipe the current Ubuntu partition (around 116GB) and then select all free space (should be around 266GB) to install my new Ubuntu on?
Do I have to do any additional steps which I am not aware of?

Cheers

Comment: Better delete the partition and create a new one in the free space.

Comment: How big is / (root) vs /home? Some prefer to have separate /home, so then they can do a new install to /, perhaps saving some settings in /etc and reuse /home during install, but NOT checking the format box. So if partitions are not next to each other that may be an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

When in the installation menu for ubuntu, you can delete your current ubuntu partition, then create a new partition spanning the freed space.

However there is an exception. If the space you freed is not next to the current Ubuntu partition, you will not be able to make one, single, larger partition.

You can use tools like `Disks` or `GParted` in Ubuntu to see how partitions are spaced on a drive. If I deleted `/dev/nvme0n1p5` in the [disk partitions image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t21Rk.png), I could not combine that space with the existing unallocated space.

Comment: So I checked and in my case the freed space is directly next to my /dev/nvme0n1p5 Ubuntu partition. That means, I can just boot from a Ubuntu USB, delete this partition (/dev/nvme0n1p5), have all the free space together and chose it for my fresh Ubuntu installation, correct? See: https://imgur.com/a/KgFjmmL

Comment: Yes, deleting `/dev/nvme0n1p5` will allow you to create a larger combined partition from the unallocated space. Make sure to back up any files you wish to keep first though ;-)